# Can't return data from SQL/Plus and Toad but can from SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle-sql-developer, toad

This one has me stumped. We are running an Oracle 11g on Amazon EC2 and I can connect and query fine with SQL Developer but with Toad and SQL/Plus I can connect but when I try to do a simple select out of v$session for example it gives me an ORA-03135 after a while. Here is what I have looked at/tried so far (in no particular order):

- Looking in the listener.log file and seeing that all three connect fine
- Turning the windows firewall completely off on the server (nothing changed)
- TNSPing from my machine resolves
- Port scanned to make sure port 1521 was open
- Used telnet to make sure 1521 was open
- Compared listener setup to oracle db on another project

Comment: Weird. Is there anything in the alert.log on the DB server? Are you using the same connect string in all 3 clients (IE: connecting by name that's in your `tnsnames.ora`, rather than host:port)

Comment: Don't see anything useful in the alert.log file for the database. I am using a TNS based connection for all 3 of them. I have tried using direct in Toad but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Any chance this could be a client driver issue? What versions do you have installed on your client machine?

Comment: I have both the full and thin client versions of 11g installed. FWIW I can connect to other 11g instances on Amazon with Toad with this configuration.

Comment: have you check the database status? not kiddin I tried everything but that... select instance_name, status from v$instance;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the network buffer is being filled but not flushed.  SQL*Net performance in this area is often managed by setting tcp.nodelay=yes in sqlnet.ora; also look at the send_buf_size and recv_buf_size parameters.

SQL*Dev working and not SQL*Plus are what pointed me to this type of troubleshooting approach.  SQL*Developer uses jdbc behind the scenes to do its fetching.

hth!

Comment: I set tcp.nodelay=yes and then set both send_buf_size and recv_buf_size according to the guidelines here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_bdp_sqlnet.htm and it worked. Thanks for the help.